# Jacobian of a map into the unit circle has rank at most 1

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I need to prove the following elementary fact in order to complete a proof for my bachelor thesis:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function that maps to the unit circle, i.e. $f_1^2+f_2^2=1$ where $f_1:=\Re(f)$ and $f_2=\Im(f)$. Then the Jacobian matrix \begin{equation} \left( \begin{array}{lll} \partial_1 f_1(x) & \cdots & \partial_N f_1(x) \\ \partial_1 f_2(x) & \cdots & \partial_N f_2(x) \end{array} \right)_{2 \times N} \end{equation} has rank 1 for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Can anybody give me a hint how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true as stated. The map could be identically constant, with derivative of rank $0$. Or it could have rank $1$ at some points and rank $0$ elsewhere. The correct statement is that the rank is **at most** $1$.

Indeed,   $0=\nabla(f_1^2+f_2^2)=2f_1\nabla f_2+2f_2\nabla f_2$.